# Create Soap Service under .net core 3.1 with existing WSDL file

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

I got very interesting issue to create soap service with existing wsdl.
Reason for that is we tried to create a testing service and all we got is a wsdl file.
What I did is

- use the dotnet-svcutil server.wsdl to generate cs file
- create new .net core service project
- create new class to implement the interface in above cs file
- services.AddSingleton<RWSv7Services, ServerRWSv7Services>();
- app.UseSoapEndpoint("/Services", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer); /*here I'm using SoapCore package*/

During testing the soap service method can be called, but I notice the Authentication in response message is not populated meanwhile the data in body message looks fine.
checked the real wsdl and my wsdl, they are different.

Correct one

```
<wsdl:operation name="listDocumentsInternal">
<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="/RetailWebServicesV7/InterfaceServices/RetailWebServicesV7Service.serviceagent/listDocumentsInternal"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal" parts="listDocumentsReq"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:soapHeader" part="operationSystem"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:soapHeader" part="vendorDetails"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:soapHeader" part="authentication"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal" parts="listDocumentsRespInternal"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:soapHeader" part="authentication"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="fault1">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="fault1"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

mine

```
<wsdl:operation name="listDocumentsInternal">
<soap:operation soapAction="/RetailWebServicesV7/InterfaceServices/RetailWebServicesV7Service.serviceagent/listDocumentsInternal" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Is anything missing?? In my mind they should be exactly same.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It is very annoying one, in SoapCore the MessageHelper.CreateHeader give different namespace to property even parameter is setup correctly. So finally I fixed by using the beta version of Soapcore because it supports CustomMessage. Create my own MessageHeader and replaces the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<RWSv7Services, CustomNamespaceMessage>("/Services", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

```
public class CustomNamespaceMessage : CustomMessage
    {
        public CustomNamespaceMessage() { }
        public CustomNamespaceMessage(Message message) : base(message) { }

        public override MessageHeaders Headers
        {
            get
            {
                var index = base.Headers.FindHeader("Authentication", "my correct namespace");
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    var xml = new XmlDocument();
                    xml.LoadXml(base.Headers[index].ToString());
                    var obj = new Authentication { };
                    var authNode = xml.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Authentication", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                    foreach(XmlNode node in authNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (node.Name.Equals("B2BAccount", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            obj.B2BAccount = node.InnerText;
                        if (node.Name.Equals("Password", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            obj.Password = node.InnerText;
                        if (node.Name.Equals("SecurityToken", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            obj.SecurityToken = node.InnerText;
                    }
                    var header = new CustomHeader(obj);
                    base.Headers.RemoveAt(index);
                    base.Headers.Add(header);

                }
                return base.Headers;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class CustomHeader : MessageHeader
    {
        private const string CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME = "Authentication";
        private const string CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMESPACE = "my correct namespace";

        private Authentication _customData;

        public Authentication CustomData
        {
            get
            {
                return _customData;
            }
        }

        public CustomHeader()
        {
        }

        public CustomHeader(Authentication customData)
        {
            _customData = customData;
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return (CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME); }
        }

        public override string Namespace
        {
            get { return (CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMESPACE); }
        }

        protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(
            System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("B2BAccount", CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMESPACE, _customData.B2BAccount);
            writer.WriteElementString("Password", CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMESPACE, _customData.Password);
            writer.WriteElementString("SecurityToken", CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMESPACE, _customData.SecurityToken);
        }
}
```